# Error while trying to import pictures with ContentHub

Tags: application-development, qml

I followed the Content Hub tutorial and I used the code about importing single pictures I found here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Content.index/

Anyway, when trying to import some photos from my app I get the following error messages:

```
void ContentTransfer::setTransfer(com::ubuntu::content::Transfer*) No valid transfer object passed: QObject(0x0)  
bool ContentTransfer::start() Transfer can't be started
```

how to fix them? I am trying it on desktop.